# Bootstrap 2 Carousel inside modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to implement a series of bootstrap modals with previous/next arrows and a carousel between them.

Here's where I'm at:

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>

        <a href="carousel-prev"> < </a>
        <a href="carousel-next"> > </a>        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This page](http://youthvoices.adobe.com/summit2013/participants) demonstrates the behaviour I'm looking to emulate.

How would I write a script in order to switch modals on click of either `a.carousel-prev` or `a.carousel-next`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your terminology slightly off, the linked page has one modal, with one carousel, which has multiple slides.

This is basically what you are looking for.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Carousel Start-->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item">
                    Slide 1
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    Slide 2
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    Slide 3
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel End -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. Don't know why my thinking was inside-out.  One last thing, how might I now link to a specific carousel item from the main page?

Comment: You can cycle the carousel to a specific slide with this bit of javascript(jquery) `$('.carousel').carousel(number);` where number is the slide number you want to open. `number` is zero-based like an array so 0 = first slide, 1 = second slide and so on...